# List all employee with salary and those with higher salary

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm working with two tables

- `Employee` (empid integer, mgrid integer, deptid integer, salary integer)
- `Dept` (deptid integer, deptname text)

How do I list all employees, their salary and the salary of the person in their department who makes the most money, but less than the employee?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You should post what you have done so far.

Comment: please can you show some sample data?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @bhuvana Just posted and answer with a sample to help OP in it's first question. Ivan, fell free to modify it to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want:

```
SELECT
    Employee.*
    , NextHighestEarner.*
FROM
    Employee
    INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        Employee.empid
        , NextHighestEarnerID = (
            SELECT TOP 1
                empid
            FROM
                Employee EmployeeSub
            WHERE
                EmployeeSub.deptID = Employee.deptid
                AND EmployeeSub.Salary < Employee.Salary
            ORDER BY
                EmployeeSub.Salary DESC
            )
    FROM
        Employee) EmployeeAndNextHighestEarner ON Employee.empid = EmployeeAndNextHighestEarner.empid
    LEFT JOIN Employee NextHighestEarner ON EmployeeAndNextHighestEarner.NextHighestEarnerID = NextHighestEarner.empid
```

This should allow you to select any details you require from the employee and NextHighestEarner sub-queries. Note the correlated sub-query in NextHighestEarnerID - this may not be performant over large datasets.

Comment: This will eliminate employees who have no other employees in their department with a lower salary

Comment: I don't believe it will - the NextHighestEarner sub-query is left joined. EmployeeAndNextHighestEarner will return an EmployeeID for everyone, and a NULL NextHighestEarnerID where there isn't anybody in the same department with a lower salary.

Comment: actually the syntax makes no sense `SELECT
        Employee.empid
        , NextHighestEarnerID = (...`.

Comment: Sorry, edited, with the help of the sample data from @jean

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with an `outer apply` to the same table:

```
declare @Employee table (empid integer, mgrid integer, deptid integer, salary integer);
declare @Dept table (deptid integer, deptname text);

insert into @Employee values
 (1,null,1,1000000)
,(2,1,1,10000)
,(3,1,1,1000)
,(4,3,1,100)
,(5,1,2,10)
,(6,5,2,1);

insert into @Dept values
 (1,'Finance')
,(2,'HR');

select e.*
        ,d.deptname
        ,es.salary as NextHighestSalary
from @Employee e
    inner join @Dept d
        on(e.deptid = d.deptid)
    outer apply(select top 1 empid
                from @Employee e2
                where e2.deptid = e.deptid
                    and e2.salary < e.salary
                order by e2.salary desc
                ) es
```

Comment: "and the **salary** of the person in their department"

Answer (score 0):

```
select      empid
           ,salary
           ,(select max(salary) from Employee as e2 where e2.deptid = e.deptid and e2.salary < e.salary)

from        Employee as e
;
```

Comment: @IvanA930 does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

Sorry to say but you looks green in SQL. 
There are lots of tutorials and good guides in the web a few good questions here in SO.

You note you will receive a few comments and downvotes because you question shows lack of effort but don't let it stop you (but try to learn a bit more before posting again).

You also can read the help section about [how to to post a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Your question lack a bit of info but I manged to create a good example using your requeriments. Use it as an simple example of Foreign Keys, Aggregates and other basic concepts.

Fell free to ask further questions.

```
--drop table Employee
--drop table Dept

create table dbo.[Employee](
  EmpId int not null identity primary key
, EmpName varchar(300) not null
, MgrId int null
, DeptId int not null
, Salary decimal(12,2) not null
)

create table dbo.[Dept](
  DeptId int not null identity primary key
, DeptName varchar(300)  not null
)
GO

alter table dbo.[Employee]  with check add constraint [FK_Employee_Dept] foreign key([DeptId])
references dbo.[Dept] ([DeptId])
GO

alter table dbo.[Employee] check constraint [FK_Employee_Dept]
GO

insert into dbo.[Dept] (DeptName)
values
 ('Dep IT')
,('Dep HR')

GO

--select * from dbo.[Dept]

insert into dbo.[Employee] (EmpName, MgrId, DeptId, Salary)
values
 ('Irwin', null, 1, 15000.99)
,('Iavin Prime', 1, 1, 4000.33)
,('Iavin IV', 2, 1, 3000.33)
,('New It guy', 1, 1, 1000.33)

,('Hermann', null, 2, 15000.99)
,('Holland', 5, 2, 4000.33)

GO

-- List dept and employees orderred by dept and salary
select dp.DeptName, ep.EmpName, ep.Salary
from dbo.Dept dp
join dbo.Employee ep on ep.DeptId = dp.DeptId
order by dp.DeptName, ep.Salary desc

-- pick highest salary by dept
select dp.DeptId, max(ep.Salary)
from dbo.Dept dp
join dbo.Employee ep on ep.DeptId = dp.DeptId
group by dp.DeptId

-- pick alle employee from each dept with matches the highest salary/dep
select dp.DeptName, ep.EmpName, ep.Salary
from dbo.Dept dp
join dbo.Employee ep on ep.DeptId = dp.DeptId
join (
        select dp.DeptId, max(ep.Salary) as TopSalary
        from dbo.Dept dp
        join dbo.Employee ep on ep.DeptId = dp.DeptId
        group by dp.DeptId
) as tsd on tsd.DeptId = ep.DeptId and ep.Salary = tsd.TopSalary
```